# Why $\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^*\omega_t=\phi_t^*(\mathcal L_{v_t}\omega_t+\frac{d}{dt}\omega_t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative

let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open and $\omega_t\in \Omega^2(U)$ a differential 2-form with  a parameter $t\in \mathbb R$.

Let $v_t\in \mathcal X(U)$ a vector field and $\phi_t$ its flow.

I don't understand why we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^*\omega_t=\phi_t^*(\mathcal L_{v_t}\omega_t+\frac{d}{dt}\omega_t)$$

I would like to use my definition which is that $\mathcal L_v\omega=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\phi_t^*\omega-\omega}{t}$ But I can't make the link unfortunately...

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [Mimic the product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608048/time-derivative-of-a-pullback-of-a-time-dependent-2-form) and pass the pullback through the limit.

Comment: @Matematleta Thank you for your answer. However in the link you've provided I do not understand the last equality in Jordan Payette's answer. It seems to me that $\psi_{t_0}^{\ast} \left\lbrack \lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{(\psi_{t_0}^{\ast})^{-1}\psi^{\ast}_{t}  - Id}{t-t_0} \right\rbrack \cdot \lim_{t \to t_0} \omega_t=\psi_{t_0}^{\ast} \left\lbrack \lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{(\psi_{t_0}^{\ast})^{-1}\psi^{\ast}_{t}  - Id}{t-t_0} \right\rbrack \cdot \omega_{t_0}=\mathcal L_{X_{t_0}}\omega_{t_0}$ instead of having $=\psi^{\ast}_{t_0} \mathcal{L}_{X_{t_0}}\omega_{t_0}$ because of my definition which is

Comment: @Matematleta which is $\mathcal L_{X_{t_0}}\omega_{t_0}=\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{\psi_t^*\omega_{t_0}-\psi_ {t_0}^*\omega_{t_0}}{t-t_0}$